# How to get stack to save dependencies?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using the `stack install` command to save dependencies for a new project. How do I get it to save those dependencies into `stack.yaml`? Unless I'm missing something, I can't see where stack is recording the project dependencies and I can't seem to find anything in a docs about this.

Comment: There is an open issue for this feature request: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1933.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still keep your dependencies in a `.cabal` file. From [the Stack FAQ](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/):

> - A .cabal file is provided for each package, and defines all package-level metadata just like it does in the cabal-install world: modules, executables, test suites, etc. No change at all on this front.
> - A stack.yaml file references 1 or more packages, and provides information on where dependencies come from.

If you need additional versions of dependencies than the LTS Haskell snapshot you're using, you'll add them to the [`extra-deps` portion of the stack.yaml file](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-a-package-than-what-is-provided-by-the-lts-haskell-snapshot-im-using-what-should-i-do).

Comment: Is there a way to automate deps being added to the cabal file? It's nice using package managers from other languages when they handle adding the dependencies with the correct version to the file for you. Or is this a deliberate design decision?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to automate it. I think it's an intentional decision based on how complex `.cabal` files can be and that you may have multiple packages and multiple `.cabal` files in a single Stack project. By nature, it isn't as simple as, for example, a `packages.json` file in a node project.

Comment: Stack also supports a `package.yaml` file, which is much simpler than `.cabal` files. [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack) turns the YAML file into a Cabal file.